# Emacs -- modify `dired-mark` to prevent moving cursor to an empty line at eob

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I have a custom function that gets dired marked file names (i.e., the names of every marked file) if more than one has been marked, or if only one, it gets the file name at point.  A problem occurs whenever the cursor is in **no-man's-land** because `dired-mark` (or me, because I'm the pilot) got overzealous on repetition and moves the cursor to a blank line at the end of the buffer where there is no file.  In that situation, the error is as follows:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "No file on this line")
  signal(error ("No file on this line"))
  error("No file on this line")
  dired-get-file-for-visit()
  (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit))
  (if (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit)) nil (let ((lawlist-filename (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t) (re-search-forward "^*" nil t)) (dired-get-marked-files) (dired-get-file-for-visit)))) (wl-draft-mailto) (attach-multiple-files lawlist-filename)))
  (lambda nil (interactive) (if (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit)) nil (let ((lawlist-filename (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t) (re-search-forward "^*" nil t)) (dired-get-marked-files) (dired-get-file-for-visit)))) (wl-draft-mailto) (attach-multiple-files lawlist-filename))))()
  funcall-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (if (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit)) nil (let ((lawlist-filename (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t) (re-search-forward "^*" nil t)) (dired-get-marked-files) (dired-get-file-for-visit)))) (wl-draft-mailto) (attach-multiple-files lawlist-filename)))))
  call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (if (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit)) nil (let ((lawlist-filename (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t) (re-search-forward "^*" nil t)) (dired-get-marked-files) (dired-get-file-for-visit)))) (wl-draft-mailto) (attach-multiple-files lawlist-filename)))) nil nil)
  command-execute((lambda nil (interactive) (if (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit)) nil (let ((lawlist-filename (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t) (re-search-forward "^*" nil t)) (dired-get-marked-files) (dired-get-file-for-visit)))) (wl-draft-mailto) (attach-multiple-files lawlist-filename)))))
```

I like the ability to hold the `dired-mark` key down for repetition, but I would like it to stop at the last line with a file in the dired-mode buffer.  Any ideas on how to accomplish that goal would be greatly appreciated.  Moving past that point, performing a test, and then returning to the previous point seems to *not* be a very efficient means of handling it.  It might be better to terminate the dired buffer at the end of the last line with a file, so that there is no blank line -- i.e., if there is no blank line at the end of the dired-mode buffer, then `dired-mark` can't go there (so that would be good?).

---

**EDIT**:  The debugger message has been updated with a complete backtrace.  The following is the custom function that may be, as @Drew suggests, the root cause of the error message that I am receiving:

```
;; E-mail attachments using Wanderlust.
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-c e") (lambda () (interactive)
  ;; if hovering over a directory, then do nothing
  (unless (file-directory-p (dired-get-file-for-visit))
    (let ((lawlist-filename
      (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t)
              (re-search-forward "^*" nil t))
        (dired-get-marked-files)
        (dired-get-file-for-visit))))
    (wl-draft-mailto)
    (attach-multiple-files lawlist-filename)))))

(defun attach-multiple-files (&optional lawlist-filename)
"Either (dired-get-marked-files) or (dired-get-file-for-visit) when exiting recursive edit."
(interactive)
  (let* (
      new-dir
      (beg (point))
      (dir "/Users/HOME/.0.data"))
      (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (and (re-search-forward "username@hostname.com" nil t) (not (re-search-forward "username@hostname.com\n" nil t)))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (newline 2))
    (catch 'done
      (while t
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (let* (
          (multi-attach-variable t)
          (next-file
            (if lawlist-filename
              lawlist-filename
              (dired-read-file-name
                (if new-dir
                  new-dir
                  dir)))) )
          (setq new-dir
            (cond
              ((and next-file (stringp next-file))
                (file-name-directory next-file))
              ((and next-file (listp next-file))
                (file-name-directory (car next-file)))))
          (cond 
            ((stringp next-file)
              (mime-edit-insert-file next-file t))
            ((listp next-file)
              (mapcar (lambda (x) (mime-edit-insert-file x t)) next-file)))
          (setq lawlist-filename nil)
          (if (not (lawlist-y-or-n-p "Attach another? "))
                (progn
                  (goto-char beg)
                  (throw 'done nil))))))))
```

Comment: 1. Where do you that error message? I don't see it with `emacs -Q` or anywhere in `dired-mark`. `dired-repeat-over-lines`  returns nil when it moves to eob. The msg is from particular actions on no-file line.  To avoid it, test whether point is on a line with a file. 2. Why do you want to stop before eob -- is it just to avoid that error msg? (3. Not directly related, but maybe of interest: with [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus) keys `C-n`, `C-p`, `down` and `up` wrap around from the end/beginning to the beginning/end.  You could do similarly for `m`, if you wanted.)

Comment: @Drew -- thank you -- I've updated the question with the custom function that may (as you suggested) be responsible for the error (rather than `dired-mark`).  There is no particular reason to stop before eob, except to avoid the error message.  From time to time I do like to look at Dired+ for nifty ideas -- I've borrowed your fancy highlighting of the dired-mode buffer -- it's a great library.

Comment: @Drew -- Thank you for helping me to zero-in on the problem.  The custom function I was using was one of my early attempts at obtaining the file names in dired-mode.  Elsewhere in my custom libraries, I had already switched over to the method used by `dired-do-create-files`.  So my custom function at issue in this thread needs to incorporate that same method.  I've posted an answer that will resolve the issue.  As always, your help is greatly appreciated!  Without your help, I probably would have ended up trying to rewrite something in dired-mode unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Previous Answer** (October 17, 2014):  The following 3 lines of code will halt the function if the cursor is not on a file or directory and if nothing has been marked:

```lisp
(when (null (dired-get-marked-files))
  (let ((debug-on-quit nil))
    (signal 'quit `("You are not on a line containing a valid file or directory."))))
```

**Revised Answer** (January 20, 2015):  The function `dired-insert-directory` may be modified to delete trailing new lines and/or whitespace at the end of the buffer as follows:

```lisp
(goto-char (point-max))
(let ((trailing-whitespace+newlines (abs (skip-chars-backward "\s\r\n\t"))))
  (when (> trailing-whitespace+newlines 0)
    (delete-char trailing-whitespace+newlines)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `defadvice` on `dired-mark` to avoid landing in no-man's-land:

```
(defadvice dired-mark (after stop-at-last-file activate)
  (when (eobp)
    (previous-line 1)))
```

The "move forward after marking" functionality is baked into `dired-mark` (actually, if you want to get into the guts of it, into `dired-repeat-over-lines`), so this advice checks if it put you on that blank line and moves you back if so.  Your last paragraph suggests you might not be super-keen on this option, but it strikes me as less troublesome than altering the dired internals.

Comment: Thank you for the idea -- I'll think about it some more in the context of my custom function, and report back.